# can you use InputStream.available() to calculate file size

Tags: java, android, size, inputstream

> should I use inputStream to calculate file size or use parcelFileDescriptor as inputstream is faster than parcelFileDescriptor

```
   public static long get_file_size_using_stream(InputStream is) {
           return is.available();
        }

    public static long get_file_size_using_pdf(ParcelFileDescriptor pfd) {
           return  pfd.getStatSize();
        }
```

Comment: Not at all, no.

Comment: Thanks, but when I run both method they return same size. I have tested it on multiple file, that why I am really confuse.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, check the docs - [InputStream.available()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#available()). To cite:

> Note that while some implementations of InputStream will return the total number of bytes in the stream, many will not.

Looks like it's not a good idea to use `available()` to calculate size.

Comment: Especially if you want to support files over 2GB. But it's not a good idea to use `available()` at all. For some reason it gives a lot of people the idea that it can be used for file sizing, non-blocking operations or multitudes of other things that it simply can't be used for.